# Alternate-split CSV Column Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command, csv

The task should be quite simple, yet I cannot figure out how to accomplish it.

Suppose I have a CSV file consisting of the following one-column data (there are actually hundreds of lines, not only six).

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
DDDDD
EEEEE
FFFFF
```

Using Powershell, I want to automate the creation of a new CSV file from the above file that splits the data into the following two tab-delimited columns.

```
AAAAA BBBBB
CCCCC DDDDD
EEEEE FFFFF
```

How can I achieve that? Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show for the first file is not a CSV file, just a text file with values each on a new line.
The result you aparently want is a tab delimited file without headers.

In PowerShell, the easiest way to do that I think is to use an indexed loop like this:

```
$fileA = Get-Content -Path 'Path\To\The\File'            # read the values as string array
$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $fileA.Count; $i += 2) {   # loop through the lines in steps of 2
   "{0}`t{1}" -f $fileA[$i], $fileA[$i + 1]              # output the values delimited with a TAB character
}

# show in console window
$result

# write to file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'Path\To\The\New\File'
```

Output:

```
AAAAA   BBBBB
CCCCC   DDDDD
EEEEE   FFFFF
```

---

If you want to create a **real CSV file** with headers, output objects instead of strings:

```
$fileA = Get-Content -Path 'Path\To\The\File'            # read the values as string array
$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $fileA.Count; $i += 2) {   # loop through the lines in steps of 2
    # output an object with column headers
    [PsCustomObject]@{ ColumnA = $fileA[$i]; ColumnB = $fileA[$i + 1] }
}

# show in console window
$result

# write to file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'Path\To\The\New\File' -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
------- -------
AAAAA   BBBBB  
CCCCC   DDDDD  
EEEEE   FFFFF
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you very much. Yes, my real problem is how to separate the values into two columns, be they in a TXT or CSV file. As long as I can get them properly split and then copied to clipboard using Set-Clipboard, I'm quite happy.

Previously, I have to move the data to an Excel file and then separate them manually using =INDEX formula. But with this Ps1 script, I can automate the data acquisition process without every touching Excel.

Thanks for the CSV with headers guide as well. I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You used the `batch-file` tag, so I have to assume, a batch file solution is ok.

Read a line, remember it and print only every second run of the loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "first="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (w.csv) do (
  if not defined first (
    set "first=%%a"
  ) else (
    echo !first! %%a
    set "first="
  )
)
if defined first echo %first% -----
```

The last line takes care of odd line counts.

Answer (score 0):

What follows is a batch file solution, which does things a little differently.

Essentially, if it's an odd line number, outputs the content followed by a horizontal tab, if its an even number, it outputs the line content followed by a carriage return and line feed. It also was written not to have issues outputting content beginning with a `;` character, or containing `!` characters.

*Please adjust only your source, and destination files on lines `4` and `5` to your own absolute, or relative, filenames before testing:*

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set {) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
Set "{s}=C:\Users\Robith\Documents\input.csv"
Set "{d}=C:\Users\Robith\Desktop\output.csv"
If Not Exist "%{s}%" GoTo :EOF
For /F %%G In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" NUL') Do Set "{r}=%%G"
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe OS Call /?
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "=="') Do Set "{t}=%%G"
(Set {n}=^
% 0x0A %
)
(   For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Type "%{s}%"
     ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V ""') Do (
        Set /A {i} += 1, {m} = {i} %% 2
        Set "{l}=%%G"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If !{m}! Equ 1 (Set /P "=!{l}!%{t}:~-1%"<NUL
        ) Else Set /P "=!{l}!%{r}%!{n}!"<NUL
        EndLocal)) 1>"%{d}%"
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set {) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
```

Comment: This is great. Very straightforward. I may also incorporate this in my answer. I'm quite new with both batch and ps1 scripting, so your detailed instruction is very helpful. Thank You.